# How to get the current window size with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browser, screen-resolution, window-size

I am running on Screen Resolution of (1366 X 768 ), but when I call `getSize().getWidth()` and `getSize().getHeight()` methods , the result I'm getting is:

> Size of Width is : 1382 Size of Height is : 744

for IE, FF and Chrome web pages. URL used: https://www.google.com

Answer (score 12):

As we know Selenium interacts with browsers and these `get` methods will retrieve info related to browsers only.  As explained in other answers very clearly, screen resolution and browser are different. The simple example below shows very clearly that the web driver is getting only the browser's dimensions.

```
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    System.out.println(driver.manage().window().getSize()); //output: (994, 718)

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    System.out.println(driver.manage().window().getSize()); //output: (1382, 744)
```

Answer (score 8):

For **python** selenium webdriver  use function [get_window_size](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get_window_size):

```
driver.get_window_size()
"""
Output:
{
  "width": 1255,
  "height": 847,
  "hCode": 939524096,
  "class": "org.openqa.selenium.Dimension"
}
"""
```

Answer (score 5):

The screen resolution and browser window size are not necessarily equal.

Resolution ([from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution)) is

> The display resolution or display modes of a digital television,
>   computer monitor or display device is the number of distinct pixels in
>   each dimension that can be displayed ... "1024 × 768" means the width is 1024 pixels and the height is 768 pixels

While `getSize()` is returning the actual *browser* size.

Answer (score 5):

```
    Dimension initial_size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int height = initial_size.getHeight();
    int width = initial_size.getWidth();
```

Comment: Hi Eyal Sooliman; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C/Program Files/Chromedriver') #Chromedriver location
print(driver.get_window_size())
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use [get_window_size()](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#get-window-size) to get the current window size as shown below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
print(driver.get_window_size()) # {'width': 945, 'height': 1012}
print(driver.get_window_size().get('width')) # 945
print(driver.get_window_size().get('height')) # 1012
print(driver.get_window_size()['width']) # 945
print(driver.get_window_size()['height']) # 1012
```