# How to find the whether the current using window is maximize or minimize in selenium 2 WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, junit4

Is there any way to find the currently used browser window is whether maximized or minimized in Selenium as I am using JUnit for make test script of automation.

Thanks,

Mohan Raj

Comment: you want to maximize the browser?

Comment: @MohanRaj You mean like this? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35697931/how-to-get-the-current-window-size-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @MahmudRiad No, I want to know my current window is already maximized or not.

Comment: If you start it maxed then you will know: 
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = ChromeDriver(options)

Comment: @MohanRaj please check my answer and let me know if it is helpful

Comment: @thelastchief yes. But I have one question is the getting size of the browser is able to varied for the different size screens ? is it means how to I identified it's maximized or minimized to my code? if it silly forgive I am an newbee for here autmation :)

Comment: @MahmudRiad I know how to maximize the window but I try to know before I want to check the My window is already maximized or not  :)

Comment: @MohanRaj i have upvoted your question so that others can get it helpful.

Comment: @MahmudRiad ok Thank you.

Comment: @MohanRaj you can upvote the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the below logic

```
org.openqa.selenium.Dimension  dm = driver.manage().window().getSize();

int relativemaxheight = 1280; // put your screen resolution height
int relativemaxwidth = 800;   // put your screen resolution width

if(dm.height < relativemaxheight && dm.width < relativemaxwidth){
    System.out.println("minimized");
}
```

Apart from this you can set default maximize capabilities when creating driver. The code will look like

```
options = ChromeOptions();
options.add_argument("--start-maximized"); 
driver = ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: dm always shows last opened window size before it was minimized. dm never shows 0, by which it can be identified that the window is minimized.

Answer (score 0):

Using document.hidden will return True/False

Code:
`var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver; var isMin= js.ExecuteScript("return document.hidden").ToString();`