# python how to check if selenium webdriver is minimized

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, minimize

the problem is i don't know how to check if browser has minimized, so how to check if browser is minimized on selenium (python)? i have tried this code:
`driver.get_window_size()`
but it will return browser size before minimized, and also i have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48114607/how-to-find-the-whether-the-current-using-window-is-maximize-or-minimize-in-sele) but there is no

```
driver.manage()
```

attribute, you can help me please

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented with `get_window_position()`. And here is what I've got:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
print('default:', driver.get_window_position())
driver.maximize_window()
print('maximized:', driver.get_window_position())
driver.minimize_window()
print('minimized:', driver.get_window_position())
```

with the result:

```
default: {'x': 10, 'y': 42}
maximized: {'x': 0, 'y': 32}
minimized: {'x': 32, 'y': 61}
```

So the maximized window always has `x = 0`. I guess other coordinates depend on the screen size. So, for my screen the minimized window will have `x = 32` or i can just check that it's higher than 10:

```
is_minimized = driver.get_window_position()['x'] > 10
print(is_minimized)  # True
```

Comment: I'am sorry, i can't do it because i want to set the webdriver position and the problem is it only work after webdriver is maximize `driver.maximize_window()` and i don't want to maximize it because it will change the window position, thanks