# How to get browser resolution with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

So i'm trying to get the width resolution of my browser page (**not the browser window size**)

My problem is that in the page im making script, when width resolution is less than 1200px some things change.

I'm able to get the window width but it's not the same as the page width resolution.

For example when i use get_window_size() i get (1200, 800) but the browser resolution actually is (1985, 750).

Is it any way i can get the browser width resolution on a selenium script?

I tried this but the value isn't saved in width:

```
width = self.driver.execute_script("$(window).width()")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with using `driver.execute_script()`. I found 4 links.

Link #1 - [Get Window Dimensions](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_outerheight.asp)

Link #2 - [Get Browser Dimensions](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp)

Link #3 - [Get Document ClientWidth](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_clientwidth.asp)

Link #4 - [Get Document ClientHeight](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_clientheight.asp)

I tested this by navigating to BBC World News and then checking the `Window Size`

```
driver.execute_script("return window.outerWidth;")
driver.execute_script("return window.outerHeight;")
```

Then, I checked the `Browser Viewport`

```
driver.execute_script("return window.innerWidth;")
driver.execute_script("return window.innerHeight;")
```

But, I think what you want is the `document.body.clientWidth` and `document.body.clientHeight`

```
driver.execute_script("return document.body.clientWidth;")
driver.execute_script("return document.body.clientHeight;")
```

When you look at the bottom program, you will see that I set the `Window Size` to 1500 by 1000. When you get to the Window Dimensions Section, you'll see the 1500 x 1000 size. 
When you get to the Browser Dimensions, you'll get the inner bowser content ( not counting the scroll-bar ) This will be a little smaller than the `Window Size` 
But, when you get to the Inner Content Dimensions Section, you'll see that the `clientHeight` is over 10,000. This, I believe, tells you the full height and width of the page.

**MAIN PROGRAM - For Reference**

```
from selenium import webdriver

def get_chrome_driver():
    """This sets up our Chrome Driver and returns it as an object"""
    path_to_chrome = "F:\Selenium_Drivers\Windows_Chrome85_Driver\chromedriver.exe"
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    
    # Browser is displayed in a custom window size
    chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1500,1000")
    
    # Removes the "This is being controlled by automation" alert / notification
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
    
    return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chrome,
                            options = chrome_options)



# Gets our chrome driver and opens our site
chrome_driver = get_chrome_driver()
chrome_driver.get("https://www.bbc.com/news/world")

print(f'Inner Content Dimensions by Document Object: ( {chrome_driver.execute_script("return document.body.clientWidth;")} , {chrome_driver.execute_script("return document.body.clientHeight;")} )')
print(f'Browser Dimensions: ( {chrome_driver.execute_script("return window.innerWidth;")} , {chrome_driver.execute_script("return window.innerHeight;")} )')
print(f'Window Dimensions: ( {chrome_driver.execute_script("return window.outerWidth;")} , {chrome_driver.execute_script("return window.outerHeight;")} )')

chrome_driver.quit()
chrome_driver.service.stop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the value that i needed was "driver.execute_script("return window.innerWidth;")"

Comment: @JulianC - No problem. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35699495/1387701

The driver object will contain screen information: `driver.manage.window.size`